# python list of dictionaries add a value by key

Tags: python

```
data = [

    {
        'name': 'Jack',
        'points': 10
    },
    {
        'name': 'John',
        'points': 12
    },
    {
        'name': 'Jack',
        'points': 15
    },
    {
        'name': 'Harry',
        'points': 11
    }
]
```

**Output**:

Jack: 25 points ,
John: 12 points ,
Harry: 11 points

Is there anyway to achieve this without using for loop ?

I can achieve this by storing key value pair or name and points and adding the points if already exists in the dictionary. But is there any alternative way to achieve this ?

Comment: *Is there anyway to achieve this without using for loop?* As far as I know, NO. Why would you think you need to avoid for-loop?

Comment: Each for-loop can be replaced by a while-loop. There are also dict comprehensions but they are actually for-loops with shorter notation.

Comment: Why do you want to do it without a `for` loop ? I mean, maybe you can use list comprehension or `join`, but any solution you will get is inherently a for loop. You will have to iterate throughout the elements of your list whatever solution you find

Comment: If you want to hide the `for` loop, you can do something silly and unreadable like `functools.reduce(lambda a, p: (a.__setitem__(p["name"], a.get(p["name"],0)+p["points"]), a)[1], data, {})` to get `{'Jack': 25, 'John': 12, 'Harry': 11}`... but please don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import groupby

key = lambda d: d['name']
result = {n: sum(v['points'] for v in vs) for n, vs in groupby(sorted(data, key=key), key)}
```

Result:

```
{'Harry': 11, 'Jack': 25, 'John': 12}
```

Comment: `groupby` only groups subsequent items with the same key. OP's data has Jack/John/Jack/Harry...

Comment: Still, there's the keyword OP dreads, `for`, in there... :)

Comment: @AKX I suppose this is not a "for loop" per se. And commonly "without using a for loop" means "in one line".